# Laravel: получить связанный с текущим пользователем id

Tags: laravel

расшифрую вопрос, а то и сам не понял. Таблица связывает работников и работодателей

```
Schema::create('workers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('organization_id')->constrained();
            $table->boolean('active')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

в классе описан метод сохранения/обновления

```
Service::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->serv_id], [
            'organization_id'   => 
            'name'              => $this->name,
            'active'            => $this->active
        ]);
```

вопрос как в этом методе получить organization_id, зная id зологиненного пользователя с помощью по первой таблицы?

Comment: сделал так, но не работает public function render()    {
        $this->userId = Auth::id();
        $this->organization_id = DB::table('workers')
            ->select('organization_id')
            ->where('user_id', '=', $this->userId)
            ->get();

        $this->services = Service::all();
        return view('livewire.services');
    }

Comment: public function store() {
        $this->organization_id = DB::table('workers')
            ->select('organization_id')
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
            ->where('active', '=', "1")
            ->get();
        Service::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->serv_id], [
            'organization_id'   => $this->organization_id,
            'name'              => $this->name,
            'active'            => $this->active
        ]);
    } Получаю значение в виде "ключ - значение". Как теперь значение получить?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store() {
        $this->validate([
            'name'              => 'required',
        ]);

        $this->organization_id = DB::table('workers')
            ->select('organization_id')
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
            ->where('active', '=', "1")
            ->value('organization_id');

        Service::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->serv_id], [
            'organization_id'   => $this->organization_id,
            'name'              => $this->name,
            'active'            => $this->active
        ]);
    }
```